# merging images from two imageviews into a single image in iOS

Tags: ios, merge, uiimageview, uiimage

I have two imageviews `view1` and `view2` having `image1` and `image2` respectively. `view1` is bigger than `view2`.

It is oriented such that `view2` is located inside `view1`. `view2` is draggable as well.

How could i write a code to merge these two images in imageviews to a single image?

Comment: Can clarify what you mean by merge? Do you want image1 pasted on top of image2, along side it, blended into it, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge two images using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. Here is a small function written with Swift 2.1.1 which takes two images and creates a single image.

```
func mergeImages (forgroundImage : UIImage, backgroundImage : UIImage) {

    let bottomImage = forgroundImage
    let topImage = backgroundImage

    let size = backgroundImage.size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    bottomImage.drawInRect(areaSize)

    topImage.drawInRect(areaSize, blendMode: .Normal, alpha: 1.0)

    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    resultImageView.image = newImage

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

You can call it like

```
mergeImages(yourImageViewOne.image!, backgroundImage: yourImageViewTwo.image!) // Call to mege images
```

And here is a [link](https://github.com/saqibomer/GiggleMerge) for further exploring.